# WCF hosting in Windows Services (Network Service)

Tags: c#, wcf, service

1. WCF Service
2. WCF service hosting in Windows Services
3. WinService log on as Network Service

Host app config :

```
<service name="StudyingControllerService.ControllerService">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://IP:PORT/ControllerService.svc"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IControllerService"
                  contract="StudyingControllerService.IControllerService" />
      </service>
```

Everything work fine in local network. (localhost)
But I want to access my service from another computers via network.

I used another computer(from another localation), did ping IP (winservice's). ping was OK.
I installed my client and tried to connect to my remote service, but connect failed.
telnet also can't establish connection.

What is wrong?

Firewalls are disconnected. (on both sides)

**On the client side telnet cant open connection to IP PORT**

Comment: Did you check your firewall setting to see if connections are allowed on that port?

Comment: I did execute netstat. and my port was there with state LISTENING

Comment: You should enable WCF tracing on both the client and the server. Look at the trace logs and it is very likely to lead you to the answer. At least it will give you some more information to post here to help people to help you :o)

Comment: What was the actual exception.

Comment: Richard, There was "A coonection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond IP"

Comment: If you google for wcf tracing and diagnostics you will find how to do it. Sorry I can't post a link but I'm away from my pc on a slow connection on my phone

Comment: To enable WCF tracing, you may read, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I enabled WCF tracing on both the client and the server. An exception thrown on the client side, message was "There was no endpoint listening at http:// IP:PORT/ControllerService.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details." message of inner exception was "Unable to connect to the remote server", and another messagem of inner exception was "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with windows service or WCF. Problem was with my internet provider.

It blocked port which used my service. So, I ask to administrator to open port. and now everything is OK.

Thanks all for answers.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. It was just abut opening the PORT on windows firewall.

Just to test if that would work, i turned off the firewall service.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Firewalls are disconnected. (on both sides)

Comment: then it probably does not have anything to do with your service. Its just that the connection between the client and server does not work. I assume you can try making a single 1 page asp.net site and put it on IIS and try accessing it from the client. if you can't you would know why even basicHttpBidning would not work with your service.

Comment: Also, you can try running the service on different credentials other than local service or network service - a custom domain account (i assume that your server and client are parts of a domain network)

Answer (score 0):

I would try changing your base address in your config file, as follows:

```
<service name="StudyingControllerService.ControllerService">
  <host>
    <baseAddresses>
      <add baseAddress="http://IP:PORT"/>
    </baseAddresses>
  </host>
  <endpoint address="ControllerService.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IControllerService"
            contract="StudyingControllerService.IControllerService" />
</service>
```

My reason for recommending this is that the base address is used to allow endpoints to be added relative to the base address - putting the endpoint in the base address may be causing the issue.

Something to try at least - a couple minutes of editing and you'll have an answer one way or the other.

Comment: no, it doesn't work too. The same exception thrown on the client side.